# Write Error and above to stderr and Verbose and above to stdout

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

How to set the configuration in `NLog` to log errors and above to `stderr` and log verbose and above to `stdout`?

```
// Setting error="true" logs all messages to stderr but I want to log only error messages
// How would I configure to log err messages to stderr and others to stdout?
 <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" error="true">
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="Level" layout="${level}" />
      <attribute name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate}" />
      <attribute name="Message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
  </target>

 <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debug,console" />

 var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
 logger.Error("Error Message"); // Writes to stderr
 logger.Verbose("Verbose Message"); // Writes to  stderr but must write to stdout
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be two targets:

```
 <target name="console" xsi:type="Console">
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="Level" layout="${level}" />
      <attribute name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate}" />
      <attribute name="Message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
 </target>
 <target name="console_error" xsi:type="Console" error="true">
    <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
      <attribute name="Level" layout="${level}" />
      <attribute name="Timestamp" layout="${longdate}" />
      <attribute name="Message" layout="${message}" />
      <attribute name="Exception" layout="${exception}" />
    </layout>
 </target>
```

And then have two rules:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="debug,console_error" />
<logger name="*" maxLevel="Info" writeTo="debug,console" />
```

Comment: But writing log.warn will log to both console and console_error, I do not need to log log.warn to console, I want to log lesser than error to console and above it to console_error How do I do it?

Comment: @user3205479 Better put on your thinking hat then :), and read about `minLevel` and `maxLevel` and do some testing.

Comment: I learnt minlevel and maxlevel and It is still logging all the messages to console and above warn to console_error

Comment: @user3205479 If you have found a bug, then create an issue at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new